# Duplicate entry in Aspectj

Tags: apache-pig, aspectj

When I try to weave the jar file using Aspectj code, I am getting

```
    java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry org/apache/pig/backend/hadoop/execu
tionengine/physicalLayer/expressionOperators/Add.class
```

I used the following command to weave the jar file

```
ajc -inpath C:\pig.jar -aspectpath C:\Aspects.jar -extdirs C:\libs -outjar C:\pig\pig.jar
```

Can any one tell me why?

Comment: What's the version of AspectJ?

Comment: Please note my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

- Well, first of all *ajc* does not know any `-extdirs` paramater, AFAIK.
- I also find it rather strange that your outjar has the same name as the injar, just in another subdirectory. This makes it easy to mistake one for another when weaving the next time or just using the library.
- <strike>The "duplicate entry" thing maybe comes from the same class being contained in *pig.jar* and *Aspects.jar*.</strike> *The "maybe" was a wrong guess, see discussion between Andy Clement and me in the comments section below. The true cause is described in update 2.*

---

**Update:**

So how can it happen that the exception you mention happens while packaging the *outjar*?

```java
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.jar.JarOutputStream;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;

public class ZipExceptionDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (JarOutputStream stream = new JarOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("foo.jar"))) {
            stream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("com/foo/One.class"));
            stream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("com/foo/Two.class"));
            stream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("com/foo/UhOh.class"));
            stream.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry("com/foo/UhOh.class"));  // uh-oh!
        }
    }
}
```

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/foo/UhOh.class
    at java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream.putNextEntry(ZipOutputStream.java:215)
    at java.util.jar.JarOutputStream.putNextEntry(JarOutputStream.java:109)
    at ZipExceptionDemo.main(ZipExceptionDemo.java:12)
```

Now your job is to find out why you have the same class in multiple JARs you want to mix into one. You even know which one to search for: `org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.physicalLayer.expressionOperators.Add`.

---

**Update 2:**

I have been able to reproduce the problem with two **JARs or directories on the *inpath* containing the same class file.** How you were able to get that error if your commandline really only has a single entry on the *inpath* as shown in your question, remains a mystery to me. Anyway, I have filed a [bug ticket](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=450809) for the problem.

Comment: aspectpath is actually just used 'for reference' and the contents found on it are not copied to the outjar. If you wanted them to be in the outjar you'd put those files on the inpath instead.

Comment: Are you sure? *Ajc* finds my aspects there and they are woven. Anyway, the problem I reproduced was about *inpath* anyway.

Comment: aspectpath is a place to look for aspects to apply to any code that goes through the process (source code or class files from inpath) - it is where aspect libraries should go. But stuff from that path shouldn't go to the outjar I don't believe (that is likely a bug if it is doing that)

Comment: You are right, as usual. I had tested the stuff auto-built by Eclipse, it had overwritten my command line stuff. Okay, so either the aspect JAR needs to be on the classpath during runtime or on the inpath during compile time (if I want everything in one output jar).

Comment: Oh, and yes, I completely agree with you that the only way I can imagine this happening is double entries on inpath. I was just commenting on aspect path.  I can imagine a jar is constructed in some strange way with two class files in it (obviously only the first one is likely used) and that input to aspectj is tripping it up when the outjar is built.

Comment: Check my Bugzilla ticket for a way to reproduce it with two inpath elements. With one, I have not investigated in detail how to contrive that.